# I want to deduct a certain amount from a column's data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to deduct Rs 300 from totalfee column in every row

How do I write this as a SQL query

Comment: from every rows it should deduct 300 in totalfee column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you want to modify the actual data

```
UPDATE yourtable 
SET totalfee =totalfee - 300
```

If this is just for a `select`

```
SELECT totalfee - 300 AS fee_post_deduction 
FROM yourtable
```

Both of these can give negative fees if you currently have any `totalfee` values less than 300 of course.